# Htaccess to 301 redirect no ending slash to ending slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domains that are displaying the same information. I would like to have the one that does not end in a slash 301 redirect to the one that does.

http://domain.com/locations/texas

http://domain.com/locations/texas/

Current Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^locations/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ search.php?type=location&slug=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the rule you have no and remove the `?` making the trailing slash a requirement:

```
RewriteRule ^locations/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ search.php?type=location&slug=$1 [L]
```

Then add this (before or after):

```
RewriteRule ^locations/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /locations/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

to redirect the browser when a request is made without the trailing slash.